# Swagger OpenAPI post application/json without requestbody

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-php

My API consumes requests only with `Header - Content-type:application/json` object.

To do the same I use:

```
 @OA\RequestBody(
    description= "Provide company search parameter",
    required= true,
    @OA\JsonContent(
        type="object",
        @OA\Property(property="company_name", type="string")
    )
 )
```

But for some requests I don't need the `RequestBody`, only hit the resource and get data. How do I do it without `RequestBody`?

P.S. This request requires a `GET` method (`POST` can be used, if that helps) but `GET` doesn't accept a `RequestBody`.

Answer (score 0):

> This case cannot be described by OAS 3.0, and the restriction on GET requestBodies is to avoid attempting to describe API behaviour which the HTTP spec says is undefined. The restriction on specifying Content-Type as a 'manually' defined header is also to ensure there is no ambiguity as to which mechanism is supposed to set this header.
>
> https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/1628

When a client is sending the `Content-Type` header, it is used to describe the body of the request (not the response)

To influence the the response type a client can send an [Accept header](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/31212/difference-between-the-accept-and-content-type-http-headers).
For example: `Accept: application/json`

Comment: Thanks. I just changed all my APIs to post.